# Using a Non-Default Manager with GenericForeignKey()

Tags: django, content-type, generics

I have altered the default manager on some of the objects which a `GenericForeignKey()` can reference such that those objects may no longer appear within that default manager.

I have other managers which will be able to find these *deleted* objects, but I see no way to tell the content types framework about them. Is this possible?

I am implementing 'soft deletion' with some models which involves the following managers:

```
from django.db import models

SDManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SDManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_deleted=False)

SDDeletedManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SDDeletedManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_deleted=True)
```

This allows me to do the following:

```
SDModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = SDManager() # Only non (soft) deleted objects
    all_objects = models.Manager() # The default manager
    deleted_objects = SDDeletedManager() # Only (soft) deleted objects
```

When using a `GenericForeignKey()` field in a model to reference an object defined such as `SDModel`, it uses the `_default_manager` attribute which evaluates to the `objects` manager, to get the reference. This means it looses references when objects are soft deleted.

This was one of the main reasons I was using `GenericForeignKey()` fields. A solution I have been milling over is implementing a lesser version of the content types framework, so that I can define my own `get_object()` which uses the `all_objects` manager to access the references object.

So my question really is:

> Is it possible to use a non-default manager with the existing content types framework so that it finds the soft deleted objects, or will I have to re implement all the parts I need from scratch?

Comment: You may need to go into more detail and post example code.

Comment: I have added more specifics to give you a clearer idea my dilemma.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but have you considered keeping "objects" as the default models.Manager and naming the SDManager something else? i.e. swapping the definitions for objects and all_objects?

Comment: Yes I have tried this, initially it seams a good idea, all code which uses `_default_manager` sees even soft deleted objects through the `all_objects` manager, whereas bespoke code nearly (always uses the objects manager) but so do related_name fields. Thus it gets more complicated to patch up the flaws using that method. Any related name fields on the `User` object for example see even soft deleted objects. I imagine it to be rather like unix permissions. You lock it down and only let specific parts see the deleted objects. Your suggestion (something I have considered) is more like Windows.

Comment: I believe you may have run into this bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14891  ...basically the use_for_related_fields, which you're supposed to add to the default manager class, doesn't work like it should.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue as you, and after diving into the documentation/source it looks like Django does not provide an out of the box way to do this. The simplest method I found was to subclass `GenericForeignKey` and then override the `__get__` method.

[The troublesome line](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/contenttypes/generic.py?order=name#L126) is where it calls:

```
rel_obj = ct.get_object_for_this_type(pk=getattr(instance, self.fk_field))
```

So this line needs to be rewritten as:

```
rel_obj = ct.model_class().all_objects.get(pk=getattr(instance, self.fk_field))
```

It's a little bit hackish but it works, and you then get to use the full power of GenericForeignKey like you usually would.